# Is the Star Wars galaxy in danger of running out of coaxium and tibanna?

Tags: star-wars, ftl-drive, energy, blasters

Coaxium is the fuel that powers a hyperdrive. It is described as rare but thousands if not millions of beings use it to all the time to power their hyperdrives. Tibanna is also very important and it is likely used by trillions as everyone seems to have a blaster. What if they run out? Both of them have to be mined so they are likely a non-renewable resource. If they run out the galaxy’s planets will be cut off from each other permanently and they will have to use slugthrowers. Is there any indication that they are afraid of not having this resource or running out?

Comment: There are multiple sources of [Tibanna gas](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tibanna). Note that Cloud City is small enough to stay off the Empire's radar, hence there must be much larger producers elsewhere.

Comment: [Coaxium](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coaxium) on the other hand seems to be the equivalent of high grade oil. Other lesser grade oils exist and we could all live without the good stuff

Comment: It is! Great danger! And the so-called Resistance will _never_ do what is necessary to maintain supplies. Thankfully, friend, salvation is at hand, an organisation with the will to ensure order and stable coaxium distribution across the galaxy. Will you lend your support to the Second Order?